# Group_concat with if condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am not much familiar with mysql here i am giving a portion of my query

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Q.gender_id SEPARATOR ' , ') FROM path_career_gender_compatibility Q WHERE Q.data_entry_id = '1') AS career_gender_compatibility
```

here i am getting result as

```
1 , 2 , 3
```

but i want record like this

```
male,female,others
```

[image: table structure]

I dont know how to use a condition inside group_concat . I hope you all understand the problem any help is appreciable.

Comment: please provide table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need `CASE expression`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(case when Q.gender_id = 1 then 'male' when Q.gender_id = 2 then 'female' else 'other' end SEPARATOR ' , ') 
FROM path_career_gender_compatibility Q 
WHERE Q.data_entry_id = '1'
```